# When is the primary server changed in a replica set of mongo db replication....?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to digest the concept of replica sets in mongodb.
I know well about replication and what is the difference between master - slave format and replica sets...?

the one I know is...
In replica set, no server is intrisically PRIMARY. But in master it is.....

Let me the other major differences.

Thanks in advance
Regards,
UDAY.

Comment: I just noticed your question topic actually consists of a question you  do not mention in your post. Might want to change that.

Comment: Yes. You are correct. I think after the first time, we initialize the setup the second time would be when some thing went wrong like primary server failover...  correct me if not.... -Thanks for the mentioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An extensive comparison between the two is here : http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Master+Slave#MasterSlave-MasterSlavevs.ReplicaSets

But you did touch and the most relevant difference in your question.

As for when primaries are changed in rep sets; they are changed if the primary becomes unavailable and the new primary will be the replication set member that is elected by the other members. Again, this information is available in detail on the mongodb site here http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Replication

Comment: Yes, I will agree with this. Thanq for the links.

Comment: No problem, good luck. The video at the main repset page is very good too.